# Check boxes selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An example of limiting check boxes for a certain number is
    [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/).

```js
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
  if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
    this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-levels-3">
  <p><strong>Which level would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
</div>
```

but it allows user to select any three from all the check boxes. How can I restrict user to select continuous three, not random three check boxes? For example, if the first check box selected by user is Level 4, then the user can only select next two (5,6) or previous two (3,2) check boxes  or one previous (3) and one next (5) check box.

Thank you.

Comment: What if they want to select 2,3,4 but start with 4? Or select 4, then 2, and then 3? There is a way to do this but I wanted to see if you thought about these use cases.

Comment: Seems like a range slider would be a cleaner interface for this. Simpler for user and simpler to code and occupy less space

Comment: @andremcgruder, thank you! Yes, the use cases you mentioned is described in my example cases. Again, If the first check box selected by user is Level 4, then the user can only select next two (4,5) or previous two check boxes (3,2).

Answer (score 2):

You have to extend your `change` event listener callback to check if (when others are checked) one of these checked ones is the previous or next sibling of the currently changed one. If so, it's ok.

Also, when unchecking, if it's the middle one, you shouldn't be able to do that. (This would otherwise create a gap.)

Time for some working example!

```js
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
  let $this = $(this);
  
  if (
    !$this.prop('checked') &&
    $this.prevAll('input').first().prop('checked') &&
    $this.nextAll('input').first().prop('checked')
  ) {
    // Don't uncheck if both neighbours are checked (would create a gap)
    $this.prop('checked', true);
  } else if (
    $this.siblings(':checked').length >= limit ||
    (
      $this.siblings(':checked').length > 0 &&
      !$this.prevAll('input').first().prop('checked') &&
      !$this.nextAll('input').first().prop('checked')
    )
  ) {
    // Don't check if limit is reached
    // or
    // none of the neighbours are checked but others are
    $this.prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-levels-3">
  <p><strong>Which level would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine! But if I wrap every input with label tag then it doesn't work. 

```<label class="lwidth"><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1</label> <br>
<label class="lwidth"><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2</label><br>
<label class="lwidth"><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3</label><br>```

Comment: @Sumon Yes ofcourse, the DOM structure is different, so when searching for next/previous sibling, you have to `.parent()` one level for the `label`, then next/previous `label` and `.find('input')` to get it corresponding input field. Just follow the logic of my code and change it to match your new structure.

Comment: Thank you but unsure which lines I need to change

Comment: You might want to read up on some of the jQuery documentation, especially the `prevAll()` and `nextAll()` methods as well as `parent()` and `first()`. The docs explain quite good what these functions do and how you can use them to find/get the right element you're looking for. See https://api.jquery.com/ and type the method names in the search field (right top side) to find the docs. Good luck!

Comment: I added some more comments to help you. I forgot, you might also want to read up on `.prop()` and `.find()` (to use instead of `.siblings()`, since the `input`s are not directly siblings anymore in your new code.

Answer (score 0):

This works no matter how you place the checkboxes on the DOM. As long as they all have the same class.

```
// listen to the checkbox change state
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
                // trck the number of checkboxes that are checked.
                var countCkecked = $('.single-checkbox:checked').length;

                // remove the error message element from the DOM.
                $('.error-message').remove();

                if (countCkecked === 3) {
                    /* 
                    The "inputState" is an array of objects which is a store of the state of the checkboxes. It trackes the checkbox index in the array 
                    that is returned from the class selector and the checked state.
                    */
                    var inputState = $('.single-checkbox').map(function(ii, val) {
                        return {
                            arrIdx: ii,
                            checked: $(val)[0].checked
                        }
                    });

                    // Creates an array of just the checkboxes that are checked.
                    var jumpIdx = inputState.filter(function(ii, item) {
                        return item.checked === true;
                    });

                    /*
                    The only checkbox that is inportant is the one that is in the middle. Being that this functionality only triggers if there
                    have been three chekboxes selected we look at the middle checkbox and determin if the one after and before it is checked.
                    */
                    if (Number(jumpIdx[0].arrIdx) === Number(jumpIdx[1].arrIdx - 1) && Number(jumpIdx[2].arrIdx) === Number(jumpIdx[1].arrIdx + 1)) {
                        // This triggers if the checkboxes that are checked are consecutive. The other checkboxes are disabled.
                        $('.single-checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
                    } else {
                        // This triggers if the checkboxes that are checked are not consecutive. An error message is displayed and all the checkboxes are enabled.
                        $('.pricing-levels-3').append('<div class="error-message">Selections must be consecutive</div>');
                        $('.pricing-levels-3').on('change', function(e) {
                            console.log(e, 'sdsdsds', $(this), $(this).find('.error-message'));
                            $(this).find('.error-message').fadeOut(5500);
                        });
                        $('.single-checkbox').attr('checked', false);
                    }
                }
            });
```